# Integrating command-line SFTP and pgp into a delphi 2010 solution, what are the options?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010, sftp, pgp

We use Delphi 2010 for development, and are looking to incorporate SFTP and pgp encryption into a inbound and outbound file transfer process. Particularly looking for a command line solution that can be integrated into a job script process we have. Does anyone know of two good free solutions we may try?

Are PGP Freeware 6.5.8 (SDK 1.7.x) or PGP 7.0, 8.0 (SDK 2.x) the best options?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd recommend [SecureBlackBox](http://eldos.com/sbb/). It supports SFTP, FTPS, OpenPGP, and quite a few more. It seems a little expensive (prices vary; they have a price calculator page based on which packages you want and how you want to license it for development - there's no run-time licensing costs, just to be clear), but they're pretty easy to use, come with full source (at least in the edition we have), and the documentation and samples seem pretty thorough. They could easily be used to build a non-GUI or console app that you could integrate however needed with your build process.

I'm not affiliated in any way with Eldos, the developers of `SecureBlackBox` - just a customer through my job.

Answer (score -1):

Chilkat has a suite of components which could be useful for you

Comment: Looks like the offer a solution for alot of languages but no native delphi components.....just active x. I dont see anything that suggests that their encryption offers pgp or anything the follows the OpenPGP standard. - thanks